# What are some good ideas to practice on the MSP430

Tags: msp430

I've got 4 launchpads (I'm a hog, I know, I got 'em while I could) and I'm getting used to the programming, e.g. the timers, ADC, PWM, LPM, etc. I don't have a lot of money and would like to do some projects to solidify my knowledge. What are some little projects I could do on a budget to have fun? The blinky apps only go so far.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are some of my projects:

blog.hodgepig.org/tag/launchpad/ — *[this site no longer exists -ed]*

You'll also find loads of great ideas over at http://www.43oh.com/

Comment: Yeah, that's some cool stuff. I really like the capacitance one. How much range can you get with that?

Comment: An inch or so...

Comment: @Matt You will get more and better answers by not accepting a question for 24-48hrs

Comment: @jobyTaffey, you may have just written that great of an answer.

Comment: @Joby, I'll vote you up if you give good ones :)

Comment: Oh you did. I would have felt guilty if there were a bunch of answers and could only accept one. I'm too humane.

Comment: BTW. I found out why they are always out of stock... you bought em all, hahaha

Comment: The first link appears to be broken...

Answer (score 9):

Try using the ultra-low power modes of the MSP430's. This is one area where TI apparently rules king, though I haven't dealt with low power MCU's so don't really know. TI has a video [showing them being powered from fruit](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Db6TWl5FSGw).

Comment: That is how they rule and what I use them for.

Answer (score 5):

You could look at interesting projects on other platforms and try to find neat ways to do them on the 430. Things like PoV, IR remotes/receivers, robots, meters (internal ADC), dataloggers, alarm systems, PIR sensors, rotary encoders, keypads, game controllers, games (that might be pushing it), clocks (put that 32k crystal to good use), fan controller... Perhaps find out if some of them can neatly be done in the interrupt driven bursty fashion to minimize active time.

Alternatively, see what neat parts (chips, displays, rotary encoders, buttons, sensors...) you can find and how to use them on the 430. Use parts with I2C, SPI, PS/2, shift regs etc.

New poject ideas I'd love to see:

- Full blown 430 JTAG and software using the launchpad.

  Other pogrammers. Maybe a 430 Bus Pirate.

  A programmer for the USB SoC on the launchpad so you could use one LP to reprogram another for some other use.

  Full writeup on a data logger.

  SD(HC) card interface.

  MIDI master/slave skeleton/library.

  Interfaces to game controllers, keypads, rotary encoders, pots...

  Join the two above :)

  Adapters for wiring random commonly available controllers to vintage computers/consoles for which compatible controllers are hard to come by today.

  Adjustable PID controller (heater, motor revs, whatever).

Photograph, write notes and publish everything of course. You're bound to get feedback and more ideas :)

Answer (score 3):

Play music. You don't need to spend one cent extra money.
http://franktu.com/playing_music.htm

Comment: How is that possible? Does the MSP430 have a speaker I've not noticed? How does it make sounds? - I'm a total newbie to EESE.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some o the projects that i have done,they mainly deals with interfacing 7 segment LED displays,serial and RS485 communication,building robots etc.

1. A DIY tutorial on building a two wheeled robot from scratch using MSP430 launchpad and L293D motor control chip.I have written a detailed account on building the robot base and electronics using commonly available materials.Source codes for controlling the robot are also provided.You can check the link below for details.

http://www.xanthium.in/make-your-own-msp430-launchpad-robot

2. controlling the DC motors connected to Launchpad through RS485 connection.The control software written in Pytho and CSharp  runs on PC and controls the motors through RS485 Protocol. Link is given below.

http://www.xanthium.in/remotely-controlling-dc-motors-using-rs485-protocol

3. Interfacing MSP430 Launchpad with 7 segment displays.

http://xanthium.in/interfacing-7-segment-led-with-msp430-launchpad

4. Creating an RS485 network between a PC and MSP430 Launchpad.

http://xanthium.in/RS485-communication-using-MAX485-and-MSP430-Launchpad